# Where's Procfile?

Tags: heroku

I'm trying to install New Relic, but it says I'll need to make changes to `Procfile`. I can't seem to find it at the root of the local copy of my app though. I'm using Django.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This page on Heroku gives a lot more information on what the procfile is:
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/procfile

You don't have to have one to deploy to Heroku, but you can manually create one to take more control over how Heroku runs your apps. As per this excerpt from the link above:

> A Procfile is not necessary to deploy apps written in most languages supported by Heroku. The platform automatically detects the language, and creates a default web process type to boot the application server.
>
> Creating an explicit Procfile is recommended for greater control and flexibility over your app.
>
> For Heroku to use your Procfile, add the Procfile to the root of your application push to Heroku:

```
$ git add .
$ git commit -m "Procfile"
$ git push heroku
...
-----> Procfile declares process types: web, worker
       Compiled slug size is 10.4MB
-----> Launching... done
       http://strong-stone-297.herokuapp.com deployed to Heroku

To git@heroku.com:strong-stone-297.git
 * [new branch]      master -> master
```

Answer (score 0):

For New Relic support, you have to explicitly tell Heroku to run a gunicorn instance within New Relic. So your `Procfile` would look something like this:

```
newrelic-admin run-program gunicorn --workers 4 --worker-class gevent --timeout 60 mysite.wsgi
```

You can turn this on or off without changing your `Procfile` by conditionally looking for your New Relic licence in the Heroku environment variables:

```
Procfile:
    web: bash scripts/heroku_run
```

```bash
scripts/heroku_run:
    #!/bin/bash

    run_command="gunicorn --workers 4 --worker-class gevent --timeout 60 mysite.wsgi"

    # Run through New Relic monitoring if add-on installed
    if [[ $NEW_RELIC_LICENSE_KEY != '' ]]; then
        newrelic-admin run-program $run_command
    else
        $run_command
    fi
```